How much precious metals are there in Jupiter?
How much precious metals are there in Jupiter? I am interested in gold, platinum, and silver.
I found one thing that was related to the amount of precious metals on Jupiter specifically, but it seems be speculation and estimates based of the rarity of those metals in earth.
None of the places listing the composition of Jupiter (such as the Wikipedia article on it or this NASA page) list any of the above metals.
I’d imagine Jupiter might have a lot of precious metals due to its size and proximity to the asteroid belt, which has a lot of precious metals indeed.

The composition of Jupiter is thought to be very similar to the composition of the Sun.
Since there is about $3\times 10^{21}$ kg of gold in the Sun, and Jupiter is 0.000955 times the mass of the Sun, then there should be about $3\times 10^{18}$ kg of gold in Jupiter.
Similar calculations can be done for the other elements.
